# Introducing new terms (Acronyms and quoted)

Tags: style

If I were to introduce a quote in my article say special economic zones (SEZ). Was the previous sentence incorrect or should it be Special Economic Zones (SEZ). Does the fact that it's a known term affect anything? Any differences between the first usage (introduction) and subsequent usages (if I don't just use the acronym).

What about quotes? If I were to call a particular group, say overbearing Asian mothers as "tigers" (ignore the fact that this concept of Tiger Moms is already existent snd treat it as completely new), do I need to always quote the word "tigers" throughout the article? Would capitalising as Tigers allow me to not quote it?

Comment: You say "article", but what kind of article are you talking about? There would probably be a major difference between news reporting, academic publishing, and current events commentary, for example (and that's not meant to be an exhaustive list of possibilities). Please [Edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Article meaning article of words not pertaining to any writing style. Asking generally.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE shoryuu.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  We only allow one question at a time here so please choose one (and do peek at our "Search on Writing" section to see if they've been asked already).  Your first question is confusing because I don't know what you mean by "introduce a quote."  What quote?  Do you mean acronym?  Is your second question about using term that is the same as an existing term, as if you just thought of it, or is it about quotation marks, or ???